# Accessing names of JSON elements with Perl

Tags: json, perl, http

I've made a query to Elasticsearch using the following code snippet:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$server_endpoint = 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_mapping?pretty=true';

$resp = $ua->get( $server_endpoint );
$myResults = $resp->content();
$decoded = JSON::XS::decode_json( $myResults );
```

Here's what the request prints (if I print out $myResults before it's decoded; also works if you just type it in the browser):

```
{"index" : {
"mappings" : {
  "type" : {
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "@version" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "FIELD1" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "FIELD2" : {
        "type" : "double"
      },
      "FIELD3" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "FIELD4" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "FIELD5" : {
        "type" : "double"
      },

      ...

      "FIELDN" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

What I'm trying to do here is access the names of the fields. I'm able to get the names of what's stored inside of them by doing something like this:

```
print "$decoded->{ \"index\" }{ \"mappings\" }{ \"type\" }{ \"properties\" }{ \"FIELD1\" }{ \"type\" }";
```

But I'm not able to print out "FIELD1" so far. I've tried printing out everything *except* for the type, but it only displays HASH(0x7ff60b345978).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `FIELD1` is a hash reference

Comment: Right. How do I access it?

Comment: You just accessed it.. If you print a hash reference it will print like `HASH(0x7ff60b345978)` I am not sure what you mean by `"print out everything *except* for type"`. You can print the keys of a hash using the `keys` keyword.. see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$decoded->{index}{mappings}{type}{properties}` is a reference to a hash of properties. You want the keys of that hash, so you use `keys`.

```
my @property_names = keys(%{ $decoded->{index}{mappings}{type}{properties} });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify what you're doing by getting rid of the unnecessary double quotes around what you are wanting to print.

Just do this:

```
print $decoded->{ "index" }{ "mappings" }{ "type" }{ "properties" }{ "FIELD1" }{ "type" };
```

or let Perl automatically turn single words in hash keys into strings for you:

```
print $decoded->{ index }{ mappings }{ type }{ properties }{ FIELD1 }{ type };
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that Perl did that. Thanks for your help!